# python how to rerun program?

Tags: python, loops

I wrote a function to generates the first `n` Fibonacci numbers. However, it keeps looping; I want it to stop and give the user the option of calculating another sequence of Fibonacci numbers. If the user enters `-1`, the process should exit.

```
#fibonacci sequence : number is the sum of the previous row numbers
def fibonacci(n):
"""Return the first N numbers of the Fibonacci sequence."""
   a,b = 0,1
   for i in range(n):
       a,b = b,a+b
   return a

#main program
print("Fibonacci Sequence")
fib = int(input("Input a number to get its Fibonacci sequence: "))
while True:
    for i in range(fib):
        print(i, fibonacci(i))
        continue    
    else:
        fib == -1 #if user inputs -1 exit
        exit()
```

Comment: That can't be your actual indentation. Can you fix it? It looks like an indentation issue because all the normal bits are there :)

Comment: i edited it now , i typed it wrong on here but this is exactly how my code it and it just keeps looping

Comment: You need to put the input in the loop if you want to do it each time. And you need an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
fib = int(input("Input a number to get its Fibonacci sequence: "))
while True:
    for i in range(fib):
        print(i, fibonacci(i))
        continue
    else:
        fib == -1
        exit()
```

use this:

```
while True:
    fib = int(input("Input a number to get its Fibonacci sequence: "))
    if fib == -1:
        break
    for i in range(fib):
        print(i, fibonacci(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `while True:` use `while fib != -1`

```
fib = int(input("Enter a numher"))
while fib != -1:
    for i in range(fib):
        print(i, fibonacci(i))
    fib = int(input("Enter a numher"))
```

Comment: I don't understand why I got a down vote. Anyone care to elaborate with some constructive criticism?

Comment: You have repeated your `fib = int...` line twice, unnecessarily, and your approach is quite confusing, because it mixes two ideas: the actual fib calculation, and the desire to simply repeat the program.

Comment: The `fib = int...` is neccesary to the execution of the program. Remove the first instance you'll get an error at the `while fib != -1:` remove the second instance then the code is stuck in an infinite loop in the case the user does not enter -1 the first time. The code is actually quite simple in my opinion. In fact I think I have provided the shortest solution but, I do not see how any of this could be confusing. @Symmitchry

Comment: I was just trying to explain why I imagine you were downvoted. (Wasn't my downvote). Duplication of code is just not ideal, is all, and `while True` is much cleaner, I think.

Comment: I respect that you were trying to explain but it was wrong and I was just explaining why I was correct. And I guess the duplication of code is just a coding style but there's no reason to not shy away from it here. Sometimes using `while True:` can lead to some ugly logic errors.

Comment: I'm not a fan of `while True`, but it's the closest thing Python has to a real `do {} while ()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("Fibonacci Sequence")
while True:
    fib =int(input("Input a number to get its Fibonacci sequence: "))
    if fib == -1:
        break
    for i in range(fib):
        print(i, fibonacci(i))
        continue
```

Comment: `continue` is redundant in this case.

Comment: I was considering mentioning that, but I believe it was included here just to emphasize what happens at that point in the loop. Its redundancy really should have been noted - which your comment takes care of.